# Connect openshift application to noobhub client

Tags: node.js, lua, websocket, openshift

I'm using noobHub with corona sdk with my local server and it works fine,
but when I put the server online (to my free openshift account) I can't connect the client application to it.

On the server side I have to set up the ip and port like this:

```
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 1337;
var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP  || 0;

server.listen(port, ip);
```

I can get the values of the openshift ip and port, tried to connect to it, but not worked.

I tried several options in my corona application, but no luck:

```
"ws://my-server.rhcloud.com, port: 8080"
"http://my-server.rhcloud.com, port: 8080"
"my-server.rhcloud.com, port: 8080"
```

My server code similar like this one (except the ip and port): [noobHub server](https://github.com/Overtorment/NoobHub/blob/master/server/node.js)
and the client code is [here](https://github.com/Overtorment/NoobHub/blob/master/client/lua-corona/main.lua).

How could I connect the client to the online server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked it at noobHub forum:

http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/32775-noobhub-free-opensource-multiplayer-and-network-messaging-for-coronasdk/page-7

The result is I will use Digitalocean's droplets for only $5 monthly, here's a great tutorial about that:

http://www.develephant.net/noobhub-multiplayer-server-for-corona-sdk-in-5-minutes